# no .sc_start file when I try to source ~/.bashrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, ubuntu-14.04

I changed $PATH at .bashrc file and I want to apply the change. But when I try source ~/.bashrc, I got following error:

```
jun@Saber:~$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/jun/.sc_start: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: As the error message says, you are trying to do something in `.bashrc` with a file called `.sc_start`. And the file does not exist.

Comment: it seems you try to execute `.sc_start`, the file could be missing as stated by fedorqui or it has no execute permissions; you can either change its permissions `chmod +x .sc_start` or change the line in `.bashrc` prepending `sh `

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks. That's why! I didn't notice I added that line before. Thank you.

Comment: @gengisdave: If the file existed but didn't have execute permissions, it wouldn't produce a "No such file or directory" message.

Comment: @Keith: you're right, I confused the error with the one when you try to execute a binary in an unsupported arch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you are trying to do something in `.bashrc` with a file called `.sc_start`. And the file does not exist. –  fedorqui